# assigning values to properties in constructor function

Tags: javascript, constructor, properties, prototype

I am working on an assignment for a JS course.

Instructions say to:
setHrs() function takes input of hours worked. function should save input to its instance variable name hrs. no returns.

Okay, so I am pretty much stuck. Below is my code, where I define the employees, give them properties, share those properties between Employee --> Employee1 --> Employee2

Once I got Employees sorted out, I need to create functions within Hourly() that I can then call on later in the program; getRate() and getHrs().

I need pointers for assigning new values to this.rate and this.hrs, here is my code:

```
//Prince of Wales, Bed and Breakfast Resort

function Employee(id, name, hiredate, position){  
  this.id = id;                                    
  this. name = name;
  this.hiredate = hiredate;
  this.position = position;
 }

Employee.prototype.hired = "Employed";

var Employee1 = new Employee("4", "Blackadder",
 "06-03-1902", "butler");

var Employee2 = new Employee("5",  "Baldrick",
 Employee1.hiredate, "who knows"); 

// printed out to test prototype works... everything above can be printed

function Hourly(rate, hrs) {
  this.rate = 0;
  this.hrs = 0;

  this.setHrs = function(){
     // set Employee1 hours
    // set Employee2 hours
  }

  this.setRate  = function() {
    // set Employee1 rate
   // set Employee2 rate
  }

}   

Hourly.prototype = new Employee();

Employee1.prototype.hrs = 50;
Employee2.prototype.hrs = 25;

Employee1.prototype.rate = 4;
Employee2.prototype.rate = 1;

console.log(
  "Name :              " , Employee1.name ,
  " Hourly Rate :    ",  Employee1.setRate(),
  " Hours Worked : ", Employee1.setHrs(),
);

console.log(
  "Name :              " , Employee2.name ,
  " Hourly Rate :    ",  Employee2.setRate(),
  " Hours Worked : ", Employee2.setHrs(),
);
```

I had thought of something else that might work, it doesn't, but I might be on the right track???

```
  this.setHrs = function(){
   Employee1.hrs = 50;
   Employee2.hrs = 25;
  }

  this.setRate  = function() {
    Employee1.rate = 4;
    Employee2.rate = 1;
  }
```

I have also thought, maybe rate and hrs should be arrays and I can push values to them, but everything I tried didn't add values to the arrays. Plus, if I do that then when I print the array, I could end up with more problems.

**SOLUTION EDIT:**

```
function Employee(id, name){
  this.id = id;
  this. name = name;
} // end of employee()

function Hourly(id, name) {

 Employee.call(this,id,name);

 var rate = 0.0;
 var hrs = 0.0;

 this.setHrs = function(time){ this.hrs = time; }

 this.setRate  = function(pay) { this.rate = pay; }
```

My main issue may have been the variable set up. I thought I understood prototypal inheritance, but there were some small details that caused my code not to run. once I changed my code from

```
this.rate = rate;
this.hrs = hrs;
```

to

```
var rate = 0;
var hrs = 0;
```

it was pretty much smooth sailing from there. Additionally, I needed to call the previous function Employee(). My employee variables are defined later in the code, but they are pretty much set up the same except for one important change... calling the appropriate function.

```
var Employee1 = new Hourly("2262124", "Blackadder");
Employee1.setHrs(50);
Employee1.setRate(4);
Employee1.getPayCheck();
console.log("  ");
```

previously, I called Employee() and that worked for assigning values to name and id, but not for setting rate and hrs which are "further" down in the inheritance chain. I then passed ALL properties to the Hourly() function and my properties were getting their values appropriately.

**I just wanted to post my solution here for others who may be having issues practicing with inheritance. Thank you for reading and commenting!!**

Answer (score 0):

> setHrs() function takes input of hours worked

You should be passing some parameters to this function. A setter function will take some input and "set" some object variable.

```
setHrs(hours)
```

You should do this for each Employee object you create.

```
Employee1.setHrs(50)
Employee2.setHrs(25)
```

I hope this helped.

**EDIT**
For clarification on what I meant:

If you were to create an Employee object like you already have

```
function Employee(id, name, hiredate, position){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.hiredate = hiredate;
    this.position = position;
}
```

Then you can instantiate Employees like this:

```
var johnSmith = new Employee("6", "John Smith", "04-28-2017", "Chef")
```

Now if we were to modify the Employee class like this:

```
function Employee(id, name, hiredate, position){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.hiredate = hiredate;
    this.position = position;
    this.setHrs = function (hours) = {
        this.hours = hours;
    }
    this.setRate = function (rate) = {
        this.rate = rate;
    }
}
```

Now you are able to instantiate the Employee object like I did above but now you can call these member functions on the object.

```
johnSmith.setHours(50);
johnSmith.setRate(25);
```

There are ways to handle inheritance if you had to handle both salary and hourly workers, but this solution will work if you only have to deal with hourly workers.

Comment: The error I get is that setRate is not a function. I put your suggestion into the console.log and process.stdout.write:

Comment: I updated my answer with a more OOP oriented approach to your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to show me what you meant. I did put the exact code you have for setHrs, setRate in Hourly(). Unfortunately, setHrs, setRate needs to be in Hourly(). Your code does solve the inheritance issue though. I added [Hourly.prototype = new Employee();] into my code outside the functions because that's how my professor says we can continue passing prototype properties. I am sure the problem is inheritance, it's just very confusing at the moment. If you know of a source where I could get a better explanation of inheritance, that would help too.

Answer (score 0):

The setter functions need to take a parameter, and then they should update the property of the current object.

```
this.setHrs = function(hours){
    this.hrs = hours;
}
```

You shouldn't be accessing `Employee1` and `Employee2` inside the methods, because the caller can have other variables containing these objects. They use those variables when they call the method:

```
Employee1.setHrs(50);
Employee2.setHrs(25);
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem was also the , instead of + in console.log

```js
    function Employee(id, name, hiredate, position){  
      this.id = id;                                    
      this. name = name;
      this.hiredate = hiredate;
      this.position = position;
      this.rate = 0;
      this.hours = 0;
     }

    Employee.prototype.hired = "Employed";
    
    Employee.prototype.setHrs =function(hours){
    
       this.hours = hours;
    
    }
    
    Employee.prototype.setRates = function(rates){
    
        this.rate = rates;
    
    }
    
    
    function Hourly (employeeContext,hours, rates){
    
      employeeContext.setRates(rates);
      employeeContext.setHrs(hours);
   
    
    }

    var Employee1 = new Employee("4", "Blackadder",
     "06-03-1902", "butler");

    var Employee2 = new Employee("5",  "Baldrick",
     Employee1.hiredate, "who knows"); 
      
      
     //calling Hourly 
     
      Hourly(Employee1, 4, 25);
      Hourly(Employee2, 1, 50);

    console.log(
      "Name :              " + Employee1.name +
      " Hourly Rate :    " + Employee1.rate+
      " Hours Worked : "+ Employee1.hours
    );

    console.log(
      "Name :              " + Employee2.name +
      " Hourly Rate :    "+ Employee2.rate+
      " Hours Worked : "+ Employee2.hours
    );
```

Comment: Thanks. I was switching between printing statements. :)